# What is causing this image ghosting on a Nikon 50mm 1.8G?

Tags: macro, motion-blur

I was photographing with my Nikon 50mm 1.8G at a garden recently and noticed some weird bokeh on some of my shots. Here's an example. Look at the back of the flower:

Settings: f/3.2 / 1/800 sec / ISO 200

[image]

[image]

I originally thought that this had to do with the narrow depth of field 
but this isn't happening at the top left of the flower which is the same depth.

What is going on here that's causing this ghosting?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like movement to me - I can see similar at the opposite side of the flower.

[image]

As it looks to be in only one plane, I'd be more inclined to think some vibration - maybe even just a footstep of someone passing -  had caused the flower to oscillate, rather than it being hand-shake, especially at 1/800.

I have seen similar when trying to do macro in my room at home - passing traffic can cause camera &/or subject shake.